# Spring boot launch hibernate config not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Hi there I am trying to create a student webapp with spring boot but i can't seem to get it to run as an error appears every time that hibernate sessionfactory can't be found and i should include a bean type of equal type in my configuration.

I thought I properly configured the webapp properly but i cant seem to get it to find my hibernate session factory which i configured in my DAO, any help on where i'm going wrong would be appreciated.

Here Spring boot launcher class

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class)
@ComponentScan({"model", "controller", "dao", "service"})
public class StudentsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StudentsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Here is my DAO class

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class StudentDao {
    
    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    
    public Student getStudent(final int id) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        TypedQuery<Student> q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
                "from student where = id").setParameter("id", id);

        return q.getSingleResult();
    }

    public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        TypedQuery<Student> q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
                "from student");

        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public void addStudent(final Student student) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(student);
    }

    public void updateStudent(final Student student) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(student);
    }

    public void deleteStudent(final int id) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
                "delete from student where = id").setParameter("id", id)
                .executeUpdate();
    }

}
```

here is my configuration class

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
public class DbConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("jdbc.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("format_sql", "true");
        props.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

        factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(props);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.alpheus.students.entity");
        // factoryBean.setAnnotatedClasses(Student.class);
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

here is my properties file

```
# Connection url for the database
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/week04
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass

server.port=9999

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

#view resolver
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

here is my controller class

```
@Controller
public class StudentController {
    
    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;
    
    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String getAllStudents(Model studentsModel) {
        List<Student> listStudents = studentService.getAllStudents();
        studentsModel.addAttribute("listStudents", listStudents);
        return "student-list";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/student/{id}")
    public String editStudent(@PathVariable int id, Model studentModel) {
        studentModel.addAttribute("student", studentService.getStudent(id));
        return "student-form";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/student/new")
    public String saveStudent(@ModelAttribute("student")Student student) {
        studentService.addStudent(student);
        return "redirect:/";    
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/student")
    public String showNewForm() {
        return "student-form";
    }
    
    
    @PostMapping("/student/update/{id}")
    public String updateStudent(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student) {
        studentService.updateStudent(student);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
    
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/student/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteStudent(@PathVariable int id) {
        studentService.deleteStudent(id);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

Comment: _Why_ are you disabling the auto-configuration, which is the whole point of Boot, and doing it manually?

Comment: @chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic not sure i understand where you specifying i am fairly new to using spring framework, but if I understand you properly get a ClassCastException if i dont exclude `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class` any way i could fix this?

Comment: @chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic I was able to get rid of the ClassCastException by removing `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
` from my application.properties file but now the application returns a 500 page error `hibernatexception: no CurrentSessionContext configured` for home page

Comment: To fix: Eliminate your configuration class; it's unnecessary. Have `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` in your dependencies. Eliminate your `StudentDao` and replace with `interface StudentDao extends JpaRespository<Student, Integer> {}`.

Comment: (And learn how to use REST verbs and paths properly: POST _means_ "create new", so don't have "new" in the path. PUT _means_ "modify the contents", so use `@PutMapping("/student/{id}")`. Same for `@DeleteMapping`.)

Comment: @ chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic I think i was able to implement your suggestions correctly but now the program refuses to launch i'm receiving an error saying it can't find the StudentDao interface and I should add it to configuration although i added a `@ComponentScan({"dao"})` to the main class and `@Repository` to the studentdao class... is there a way to circumvent this error i tried using @EntityScan but i still receive the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236312/discussion-between-alpheus-and-chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic).